# SharePoint 2010 - Access denied during ApplyWebConfigModifications()

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have SharePoint 2010 installed on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine which is also hosting SQL Sever 2008 R2.  I am attempting to deploy a solution that includes web parts in the 2010 environment that is working fine in MOSS 2007.

The Web Part feature has a feature receiver that updates the web.config.  When I try to activate the feature through the Site Collection Feature GUI, I receive an access denied message.  I am logged on to the server and in SharePoint with the APP Pool account which is also a member of the domain administrator group, local administrator group and SharePoint Farm Admin group.  This account is also dbo on SQL Server.

This same feature activates fine using the stsadm command.

I have dug into this issue at length and here is what I have found:

Looking at the Microsoft assemblies in reflector, my error is coming from the SPWebApplication.ApplyWebConfigModifications() method.  I can see the trace statements from SPWebConfigFileChanges.RemoveModificationsWebConfigXMLDocument and SPWebConfigFileChanges.ApplyModificationsWebConfigXMLDocument.  The next line is a Save(str).

Below is the output from the SharePoint logs that pertain to this error:

> Apply web config modifications to web
>   app
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   General                           8grn
>   Medium      WebConfigModification:
>   Applying web config modifications to
>   web app in server tw-s1-m4400-007
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          88gw
>   Medium      WebConfigModification:
>   Applying web config modifications to
>   file
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2008\web.config
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          887b
>   Medium      Removing web config node -
>   Path
>   configuration/system.web/httpModules
>   Node name
>   add[@name='JivePageController']
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          887b
>   Medium      Removing web config node -
>   Path
>   configuration/system.web/httpHandlers
>   Node name
>   add[@path='ScriptResource.axd']
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          887b
>   Medium      Removing web config node -
>   Path
>   configuration/runtime/*[local-name()="assemblyBinding"
>   and
>   namespace-uri()="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"]
>   Node name
>   *[local-name()="dependentAssembly"][*/@name="System.Web.Extensions.Design"]
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          887b
>   Medium      Removing web config node -
>   Path
>   configuration/runtime/*[local-name()="assemblyBinding"
>   and
>   namespace-uri()="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"]
>   Node name
>   *[local-name()="dependentAssembly"][*/@name="System.Web.Extensions"]
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          8gp8
>   Medium      WebConfigModification:
>   Adding web config node - Path -
>   configuration/runtime/*[local-name()="assemblyBinding"
>   and
>   namespace-uri()="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"]
>   Node name -
>   *[local-name()="dependentAssembly"][*/@name="System.Web.Extensions"]
>   Node value -
>   
>   in web.config file
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2008\web.config
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          8gp8
>   Medium      WebConfigModification:
>   Adding web config node - Path -
>   configuration/runtime/*[local-name()="assemblyBinding"
>   and
>   namespace-uri()="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"]
>   Node name -
>   *[local-name()="dependentAssembly"][*/@name="System.Web.Extensions.Design"]
>   Node value -
>    in web.config
>   file
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2008\web.config
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          8gp8
>   Medium      WebConfigModification:
>   Adding web config node - Path -
>   configuration/system.web/httpHandlers
>   Node name -
>   add[@path='ScriptResource.axd'] Node
>   value -  in web.config file
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2008\web.config
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          8gp8
>   Medium      WebConfigModification:
>   Adding web config node - Path -
>   configuration/system.web/httpModules
>   Node name -
>   add[@name='JivePageController'] Node
>   value -  in web.config file
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2008\web.config
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.09     w3wp.exe
>   (0x15C4)
>   0x1444    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          e5mb
>   Medium      WcfReceiveRequest:
>   LocalAddress:
>   'http://tw-s1-m4400-007.jivedemo.local:32843/15702467ece1408f881abeabac3b5077/MetadataWebService.svc'
>   Channel:
>   'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel'
>   Action: xxx MessageId:
>   'urn:uuid:4e859532-ed7f-4937-8b88-68d3af43d589'
>   9f403ede-2c94-490b-a05c-e169cc5fe58d
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.10     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          f6kh
>   High        WebConfigModification:
>   Save of web.config file
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2008\web.config
>   for applying modifications to web app
>   SharePoint - 2008 failed. Error
>   message - Access to the path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2008\web.config'
>   is denied.
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b
>
> 02/24/2010 16:05:41.10     w3wp.exe
>   (0x0F64)
>   0x1034    SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                          8j2o
>   High        WebConfigModification:
>   Changes not applied to web application
>   SharePoint - 2008 with Url xxx
>   5a817a37-7bf6-4d26-be51-207369e38f5b

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the code in your Feature that makes the web.config change.  There are a two ways of making the change.  One technique does it through a job and the other does it by making the change inprocess.

Comment: Here are the main 2 lines.  The rest of the code is spread across a number of "helper" methods.

_webApplication.WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
_webApplication.Update();

Can you point me to the "two ways of making the change" that you mention?

Answer (score 3):

Check whether UAC (User Account Control) is on and [turn it off if this is a test/demo environment](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off). The other option (and the best option for Production environments) is to right click the central admin link and choose the option to 'Run as Administrator'.

I got burnt by this for a little while and the reason is because of the way the security check is performed before the solution deployment job runs. If you are running with UAC enabled then this check will always fail (see the Remarks section on MSDN for system.security.principal.windowsprincipal).

Comment: I wsnt allowed to add another link (new user restriction) but the MSDN link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.aspx

Comment: (filling in for Tim who needed to move on to other problems)  This is a feature scoped to a site collection, so I can't activate it via central admin.  For grins, I tried running IE on the SharePoint server  by doing a runas administrator.  Not surprisingly, when activating the feature it still fails.

Comment: Tim just told me that if you do a runas administrator to run SP Central Admin that you actually get additional links to administer services.  Very interesting.  I don't see links to activate site collection features, though :-(.

Comment: Just tried turning off the UAC (had to reboot after doing so).  It didn't help either :-(.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question close enough. It was the access denied that was common to my issue. Given your activating your feature from your SC Id be interested to know what behavior you get if you wrap your code in a RunWithElevatedPrivileges block. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466220.aspx

Comment: This worked for me - why/how is beyond me (server side being influenced by the account running the client side process?)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the identity of your application pool has read/write access to directory that contains the web.config.

Also make sure the identity of your SharePoint Timer Job has read/write access to the directory that contains the web.config file.

Comment: In this test environment, I am using the same account for everything and it is also the same account I am logged on the machine with.  It is an administrator on the machine, a farm admin in SharePoint, site collection administrator in SharePoint.  And when I run the STSADM -o activate feature using this account, it works fine.  It only fails when I use the UI.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the feature's scope to WebApplication and activating it from within Central Admin

Comment: the feature is adding WebParts.  I would need to separate out the Web.config modifications from the associated web parts to do this since my feature contains modules.

Answer (score 0):

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2008\web.config
>   for applying modifications to web app
>   SharePoint - 2008 failed. Error
>   message - **Access to the path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2008\web.config'
>   is denied.**

Check this file permissions and adjust them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to reorganize our feature architecture such that we now have a Web Application scoped feature in addition to 2 Farm scoped features and 2 Site Collection scoped features.  We moved our code that dealt with WebConfigModifications from our site collection scoped features to our new web application scoped feature.

This was the way it should have been done all along (and how we tried to do it initially a while back), but the SharePoint Solution Installer did not support our feature architecture so we worked around it by having a bit of code trying to deal with WebConfigModifications at the site collection level.  This had some rough side-effects like requiring the account that activated the site collection feature to also be a farm administrator - and we had to have some smart code to not apply or remove our settings multiple times.

So, we had to update the SharePoint Solution Installer for this - and also get it to work in SharePoint 2010.  It is not released yet, but watch http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/ for releases that support this scenario for both SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010.